# MS Visual Studio 2010 Error Message

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction

I have spent all day trying to get a program working. Now, MS Studio 10 stopped compiling, with an error message,

> fatal error LNK1168: cannot open K:\Continuing Education\CCCCD\COSC1436\Prog10\Debug\Prog10.exe for writing

I'm guessing this means it ran out of memory somewhere. What do I need to do to get it working, again?

Comment: Never mind, I got it working, again. I closed out the program and re-opened it.

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons:

- You have an instance of Prog10.exe running
- `K:` drive is full
- If `K:`is a network drive, it went offline.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have write permission to the mentioned directory. Is that where your project is stored? 
The error message is telling you that it couldn't write out the exe file, which usually means there's something wrong with write permissions for that directory.